# Overflow:hidden not working

Tags: css, background

When I run my code in a browser, the background is exactly where I already want it to be, the problem is that I can still scroll down, revealing the part of the background which is originally hidden. I need it so that the picture which I am trying to input does not come off the page, and does not reveal any more of the background.
Here is my code (Sorry I know it's sloppy):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>XXX</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
    body {
        background-image:url("Images/Background2.png");
        background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
    .cf img.bottom:hover {
        opacity:0;
        overflow:hidden;
}

    #container1 {
        position:relevant;
}
    #positioning {
            position:absolute;
        Top:500px;
        Left:500px;
        Width:1000px;
        Height:600px;
        overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:38px; LEFT:90px; WIDTH:220px; HEIGHT:25px" SRC="Images\Logo.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        <div class="cf">
            <img class="top" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:255px; LEFT:106px; WIDTH:140px; HEIGHT:26px" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\Contact_001.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <img class="bottom" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:255px; LEFT:106px; WIDTH:140px; HEIGHT:26px" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\Contact_002.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <img class="top" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:355px; LEFT:105px; WIDTH:120px; HEIGHT:25px" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\About_001.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <img class="bottom" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:355px; LEFT:105px; WIDTH:120px; HEIGHT:25px" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\About_002.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <img class="top" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:455px; LEFT:108px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:24px" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\Work_001.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <img class="bottom" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:455px; LEFT:108px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:24px" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\Work_002.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <img class="top" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:555px; LEFT:115px; WIDTH:280px; HEIGHT:30px" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\WTU_001.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
            <img class="bottom" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:555px; LEFT:115px; WIDTH:280px; HEIGHT:30px" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\WTU_002.png" border:"0" draggable="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
        </div>

            <div id="container1">
                <div id="positioning">
                     <img class="bottom" SRC="C:\Users\children\Desktop\PortfolioConcept_001\Images\Photoshop1.png">
     </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I did not use a stylesheet at all, thanks in advance to anyone who trys to help.

Comment: can you post a link to a live preview. It's hard to find the issue this way.

Comment: I believe IMG STYLE is basically a stylesheet but for only a certain image.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
body { 
       overflow-x: hidden;
       overflow-y: hidden;
     }
```

Comment: It will hide the contents of the page if he has a browser window with less than 600px in height and 1000px in width?

Comment: You Are Right @madhushankarox

Comment: Not exactly, the page dimensions are 1920 by 1080, the code that you gave me removes scroll bars, but I am still able to scroll down and scroll lower that the background, I need it to be no matter what the dimensions of the image are, the window will always remain 1920x1080, and will remain unscrollable.

Comment: Here is what I am talking about:
http://imgur.com/N1vkP3I
If the image is larger than the window, then overflow becomes disabled

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#positioning {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nope, same problem, there is still a falloff.

Comment: please give me a live link so I can try.

Comment: It's fine, thanks a lot to both of you, I have found my answer :) cheers.